# block cookies from beeing set in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies

As in the new eu-gdpr, a user must be able to decline setting of specific cookies.

As some of the installed plugins uses cookies, I want to block them within my own plugin.
Is there anything like a 'beforecookieset' event or something that I could hook into to prevent setting the cookies?

Comment: Depends on what is actually setting those cookies. Also notice that cookies that have a technical purpose (like keeping you logged in a website) do not fall under those laws.

Comment: Ye-es ... you have to evaluate every cookie on your site (which is super-fun when the marketing team can add anything they like via Google Tag Manager) determine which are mandatory for the site to function (as those are exempt) ... *then* work out where the rest all come from and prevent the scripts that set them from running... we decided to use Cookiebot, made life a lot easier.

Comment: why cant you try some wordpress plugins to block cookies

Comment: @charankumar I want to integrate that into my own plugin